# redirect fails for some networks

Tags: http, https, dns

This is a tough one, brace yourselves.

I'm troubleshooting some ad links for a client, as it turns out redirects from their server seem to not be coming back based on the network I'm on.

The question is:

- **How can a GET request fail based on the network the client is on?**
- **If it's a firewall thing, how can I prove that their is something in
  the response that would trip so many network firewalls?**
- **If there is an in-proper DNS record to blame, how do I prove that?**

The link:

- www.switchdriver.com

It works 95% of the time on:

- Home network
- LTE I
- https://isitup.org/

It doesn't work at all on:

- Office network
- Wife's office network
- Hotel Wifi networks
- Schools

What should be happening here is:

1. GET www.switchdirver.com
2. Returns - > 301
3. Redirect -> GET https://www.worx.com/switchdriver-20v-cordless-drill-driver-wx176l.html?utm_source=sftv&utm_medium=tv&utm_campaign=switchdriver
4. Returns -> HTML Doc

Linked below are examples I took from fiddler of www.SwitchDriver.com successfully redirecting on my LTE network and failing on my office network.

- [Success](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fxvm1gU4YuppIzEO01OZRT5z3w10ifpQ/view?usp=sharing)
- [Fail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Ruh6iWRSEwEklDU-Z0nrmmxAxPOnssf/view?usp=sharing)

Below is python code for testing the site.  If you run it you'll quickly learn weather this works on your network or not.

```
import http.client
import urllib.parse

FiddleHost = "127.0.0.1"
FiddlePort = 8888

####Test www.switchdriver.com content####
#conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(f"{FiddleHost}:{FiddlePort}")
#conn.set_tunnel("www.switchdriver.com")
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.switchdriver.com")
conn.request('GET', '/')
response = conn.getresponse()
response.status

content = response.read()
redirectUrl = response.headers['Location']
assert response.status == 301

urlparts = urllib.parse.urlparse(redirectUrl)
#conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(f"{FiddleHost}:{FiddlePort}")
#conn.set_tunnel(urlparts.netloc)
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(urlparts.netloc)
conn.request('GET', f"{urlparts.path}?{urlparts.query}")
response = conn.getresponse()
response.status

content = response.read()
assert response.status==200

response.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: It looks like a firewall thing (and it is not because of anything in response, connection is just not established at all), but I can't tell which firewall (it dos not work from my company network, and it works fin from my home. It could also be misconfigured routing on server side. You should probably get in touch with godaddy support.